# Intercepting angulargs http calls

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

ok, so here is the issue. I am trying to combine angularjs and spin js for making XHR calls, and want to show a spin loading div while call is in progress. I am using spinjs for this. now my issue is either making a directive, but in that case i have to use this to call this directive everywhere. Another option I was thinking about was intercepting http calls like a watch on it. By this way developers dont have to call my directive, they have to just use the angularjs custom $http and spinner will come on its own( as i will be extending the $http directive).
However I am not aware if this could be done. Could someone site any example? 
i have followed this https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/72ukcZYeWGE/Qaspjc0qIcgJ but without any success. Please advice me, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, using [angularjs http interceptors](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#description_interceptors) is the best option here

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
       // start spinjs
    },

    'response': function(response) {
       // end spinjs
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/K7DCN/68/ any idea why this errors out?

Comment: @neoeahit Updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/K7DCN/72/). Also the error stays, because of cross domain requests.

Comment: Thanks @Andrey. Please check below fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/P7xXb/1/
Question: does using httpProvider.interceptor cause a change in response headers?
I have used the example from $http in angularjs, but added the code modified by u in your fiddle. The same working example fails in this case?

Comment: @neoeahit Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/P7xXb/2/) out. You we forgot to return promises in interseptors. Also never use alerts there - they pause JS execution and everything brakes.

Comment: Ah! Ouch!
Thanks so much! I wish I could give you more +1's